# Function with intinity loop

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea, where user can input any js code, when i run it with

```js
const userCode = "while(true);"
const func = new Function("", userCode);

func();
```

And web-page freezes, what I can do? May be use WebWorker?

Comment: What is the objective of executing the code?

Comment: @CertainPerformance example: IDE for run javascript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A worker is possible, but workers don't have access to many things script-writers usually expect to have access to on the front-end. Consider putting the code into a sandboxed iframe instead - this will not only keep the top tab responsive and permit access to more objects, it'll also be much safer. This is the technique that Stack Snippets and other live code editors on websites use.

Take the user's code, and send it to a mini-backend which takes the user's script and and inserts it into a `<script>` tag:

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form target=iframe method=post action="https://stacksnippets.net/js">
  <button>Run</button>
  <textarea name="js" rows=4 cols=100>console.log('user should insert code into this textarea');</textarea>
</form>
<iframe name=iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups"></iframe>
```

Or, for an endless loop:

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form target=iframe method=post action="https://stacksnippets.net/js">
  <button>Run</button>
  <textarea name="js" rows=4 cols=100>while (true);</textarea>
</form>
<iframe name=iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups"></iframe>
```

The above will consume a lot of resources, but you'll see that the Stack Overflow (and snippet) page remains responsive. Only the inner iframe will be unresponsive due to the infinite loop.

Here, all that `https://stacksnippets.net/js` does is it takes the code from the `js` in the form, and inserts it into the HTML response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    test
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // USER'S CODE GOES HERE
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Have your backend do the same thing.

Comment: your second snippet still freezes when i click run, it so conceived? I've thinked, it would be running in iframe and don't block other interface

Comment: Oops, you're right, it looks like the data src takes the resources of the parent page. Need to post to a standalone page instead of creating it from a data URI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not have an infinity loop, try adding `onchange=''` and execute stuff only when there was a user interaction. This could be also extended by adding a debounce or throttling to make sure the user is finished with the changes.

Or even have a button for execution! :)